# What happens if VHDL calls an infinite recursive function?

Tags: vhdl

What happens in a design if VHDL calls an infinite recursive function? E.g. if I write some random code like:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity recursion is
port ( num : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
           exor_out : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
                    );
end recursion;

architecture Behavioral of recursion is

function exor( num : std_logic_vector ) return std_logic_vector is
variable numf : std_logic_vector(num'length-1 downto 0):=(others => '0');
variable exorf : std_logic_vector((num'length/2)-1 downto 0):=(others => '0');

begin
numf := num;
exorf := exor(numf(num'length-1 downto num'length/2)) xor exor(numf((num'length/2)-1 downto 0));
return exorf;
end exor;

begin
exor_out <= exor(num);
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: In simulation you will recurse forever as soon as `num'length` reaches 1. In synthesis it depends on your synthesizer but I guess that most of them should issue an error because they could not unroll your recursion.

Comment: It's implementation defined and not part of the standard. See [VHDL Recursion and Useful Error Messages](http://insights.sigasi.com/tech/vhdl-recursion-and-useful-error-messages.html).